# Shrink worn-out SSD to prolong lifetime?

Tags: ssd, hard-drive-failure

I have a 120GB OCZ Agility 3 SSD (latest 2.25 Firmware) which is recognized in BIOS and has the following symptoms when compared to another OCZ SSD in the same machine:

- the wear level counter in SMART shows that the drive is worn out, i.e. no spare sectos left
- writing is very slow (about 1,5MB/sec)
- the SSD disconnects itself about every 20-30 seconds
- installing the OS was very slow (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case) and booting does not work afterwards (cannot find rootfs)

I assume that the symptoms are due to the fact that the drive is really worn out. My question is: Is there a way to tell the firmware to make it a smaller SSD (e.g. just 90GB, having 30GB more spares) and continue using it?

Only technical hints please --- no ecenomic suggestions ("buy a new drive, they are cheap" etc.). Thank you!

Comment: Some SSD manufacturers (for instance Corsair) let you mess with the "overprovision". OCZ has a SSD toolbox software but does not appear to have that function. Just replace the ssd, an 120GB is pretty cheap these days.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, the term "overprovision" was what I was looking for. Actually, the OCZ is also a sandforce-based SSD, but I assume that Corsair's tool won't work on it. Is there some generic tool for sandforce drives or is there a way to trick corsair's tool to manipulate an OCZ SSD?